# Accidentally deleted Windows boot manager

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, grub

While installing Ubuntu 14.10 onto a partition of one of my two hard drives, I've accidentally deleted my Windows 8.1 boot manager that was on my other hard drive.
How can I fix this so that I chose what OS I want to boot up into with grub?
I do not have a recovery disk but can I use a USB?

Answer (score 2):

This tool [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) has saved my hide a couple of times.
On boot it prompts you to run batch of automatic fixes that can restore a bootloader to proper working order.

As for getting it onto a flash drive: on linux you would use the command

```
dd bs=4M if=link/to/your/downloaded/iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Replace sdb with wherever your flash drive is mounted. Do not point to the wrong device or you could end up wiping your disk. You will also have to reformat your flashdrive to undo this.

If that's too intimidating there are tools like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) ( [UNetbootin homepage](https://unetbootin.github.io/) ), that can get the iso onto your flash drive for you.